# How to chain and merge two observables by passing the payload from one to another

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have two requests. Request`A` getting the initial data and then passing the ids from that to request to `B` to get the rest data accociated with tha entities from request `A`. Then I need to merge the datasets by `id`

Here is what I achieved so far, but here is an issue

```
let ids;
this.getAData(filters).pipe(
  tap((aData) => (ids = aData.map(o => o.id))),
  flatMap(() => this.getBData(ids))
)
.subscribe((data: any) => {
  // was going to merge the two datasets by `ids` here
});
```

The issue is that in `subscribe` am getting only the data from the second observable `this.getBData(ids)`.

Both `getAData()` and `getBData(...)` has the same method signature `Observable<Thing[]>`

How to fix that?

I am using `6.0.0-rc.7` and angular `6.0.0-rc.5`

Comment: What does `getBData` return? An array? An observable? If an observable, an observable of what?

Comment: @cartant both `getAData()` and `getBData(...)` have same signature`Observable<Thing[]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write like this:

```
this.getAData(filters)
    .pipe(
      flatMap(aData => {
        const ids = aData.map(({ id }) => id);
        const bData$ = this.getBData(ids);

        return Observable.zip(
          Rx.Observable.of(aData),
          bData$
        );          
      })
    )
    .subscribe(([aData, bData]) => {
      // Merge aData and bData
    });
```

Note:

- You may need to handle error if one of the two fails (with `catchError`)

Comment: @sreginogemoh The `zip` method may take another parameter, a merge function, so you can merge them inside that method, but it's not recomended if the method is complex. Other than that, merge the data in a `map` after the `flatMap` should do the trick.

Comment: yeah the `map` it is what I ended up with

Comment: any thoughts on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868347/how-to-handle-an-empty-result-with-rxjs-observable ?