# How to handle an empty result with rxjs observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an API that might return `[]` result.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2018 06:06:22 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:...

[]
```

Here is my code that just does not work in that particular case:

```
getData(): Observable<Thing[]> {
    return this.getData1()
    .pipe(
      flatMap(aData => {
        const ids = aData.map(({ id }) => id);
        const bData = this.getBData(ids); // emty result might be here

        //test subscribe
        this.getBData(ids).subscribe((data) => {
          //just had that for a test, to confirm subsscribe never fires when response is `[]`
          console.log(data);
        });

        return Observable.zip(
          Observable.of(aData),
          bData
        );
      }),
      // map does not executing when api that getting called by `this.getBData(ids)` returns `[]`
      map(([aData, bData]) => {
        // Merge the results
        const data: any = aData.concat(bData).reduce((acc, x) => {
          acc[x.scriptNumber] = Object.assign(acc[x.scriptNumber] || {}, x);
          return acc;
        }, {});
        return Object.values(data);
      })
    );
  }
```

`this.getBData(ids);` executing the http call and returns type of `Observable<Thing[]>`:

```
  getBData(ids):Observable<Thing[]> {
    const filters = {
      'id': [ids],
    };
    return this.http.post<Thing[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/thing', JSON.stringify(filters), {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    });
  }
```

I have no errors on console.

What is the best practice to handle that scenario?

#### UPDATE:

I did change the api so now it is returns the data this way:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 17 Apr 2018 09:36:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:...

{
  data: [],
  error: 'OK'
}
```

This way I always have the data in responce and my code works with a small modifications (`aData.data` and `bData.data`) however I still wonder why it didnt wrok in case of empty array, as @DanielWStrimpel commented it should emmit a value anyway...?

Comment: An empty array should still emit a value on your stream. Did you try to catch any errors before your subscribe to see if something else is going on?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel not really cathing an errors but have nothng looking like an error in console

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel just addded some more details (UPDATE section)

Comment: So, the log in the "test subscribe" block return empty array? Does it work if you remove that block?

Comment: @sreginogemoh, tried to reproduce your case, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-to-handle-an-empty-result-with-rxjs-observable. It works

Comment: @Tr1et didn't have `test subscribe`, just put that for debugging purposes so it is does not block anything

Comment: In the `Test subscribe` block, do you mean that the `subscribe` after `getBData` never get called? `getBData` return nothing?

Comment: @Tr1et `.subscribe()` the code never gets executed, means no values being emmited incase server responce `[]`

Comment: Yeah, then somehow, if the sever return an empty response, the `post` method of Angular will not emits items, only complete the request. I don't use Angular so I don't know about its `post` method, but it seems that adding `status` field like you do is the correct choice.

Comment: @Tr1et do you think is there a way to hook up in to obervable `complete` and to the magic in case if `[]` gets returned?

Comment: Do you mean how to listen on the Observable "complete" event?

Comment: @Tr1et yeah I wonder how tould you stick that event in to my observable and check if `bData` was actually empty and if it is just to retrun whatever is in `aData` or something like that. This way I do not need to tuch the api side.

Comment: I've post an answer below, please review it.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a problem with your `post` method (perceive empty array as no response body) or your API (return empty response body instead of empty array), either ways, now when you get empty data, it will just complete the request and return nothing.

Second, there is a workaround for this problem (while I prefer to add the `status` field to the response body like you did), is to use RxJS [toArray](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray), like this:

```
this.getBData(ids)
    .pipe(toArray())
    .subscribe(([bData]) => {
      // Process the data
    });
```

Note: As you can see, `toArray` emits an array of all items that the Observable emitted, that mean that in your case, if will return either an empty array or an array contains your data array `[[item1, item2]]`.